# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DataTransformer' on Gunicorn-hosted Flask app, works locally

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, gunicorn, attributeerror

I'm encountering an AttributeError

```
Can't get attribute 'DataTransformer' on <module '__main__' from '/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/gunicorn'
```

when running my machine learning model on a Flask app hosted by Gunicorn. Strangely, the code works without errors when executed locally. The 'DataTransformer' attribute is a custom class defined in a separate file and imported into my main.py.

How come this works locally but not when its running on Gunicorn

**main.py:**

```py
from transformers import DataTransformer, DataVectorizer, Optimizer
...other imports

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

model = load_model('model_name')

...rest of code
```

**transformers.py:**

```py
...imports

class DataTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   ... rest of code
```